# Manipulating dates in the datastore

Tags: python, database, google-app-engine

I've recently been playing around with Google's AppEngine and I seem to have gotten stuck. I'm trying to create a query that selects posts that are before a certain date (in this case, the date is now - 1 day). I've tried a few different methods in order to accomplish this, but none have worked. One of which involved converting all the dates to UNIX time and running a query like this:

```
db.GqlQuery("SELECT __key__ FROM Post WHERE date-84600 < %s LIMIT 10, ORDER BY date DESC" % time.time())
```

But after trying that, I got a syntax error which told me GQL didn't have support for operations such as subtracting in the queries.

Does anyone have any idea as to how I could accomplish this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Quick comment.  If it's saying that it can't subtract, it's probably due to the name `date-84600`.  Have you tried encapsulating it in single quotes, or whatever mechanism the GQL syntax allows for quoting a column name?

Comment: Converting the entire database over to seconds last time was a drag, so I'm going to wait a little while and see if I get any other answers, otherwise I'll try this out and see if that was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you build your query [using methods](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass.html)?

```
query = Post.all()
query.filter('date < ', datetime.datetime - 84600)
results = query.fetch(limit=10)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the math outside of the query:

```
db.GqlQuery("SELECT __key__ FROM Post WHERE date < :1 LIMIT 10, ORDER BY date DESC", (time.time() - 84600))
```